# Codeigniter url creation for newly added product in database

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Hi I recently started developing with CodeIgniter 3 and pretty new to MVC.

I am stuck to a point where I don't know where to start from. I have successfully created template, login & registration system, database and product insert script. And it does insert the fields in database.

Now my problem is how to go about giving an auto generated url for newly added product and I can't seem to find information about it.

Seeking your help.

Comment: Have you tried asking on the codeIgniter forum http://forum.codeigniter.com/

Comment: do you mean getting some sort of product ID from the URL?

Comment: yes, I mean how to go about url part so that I can pull my product from db. Also if I can include product id in that, it would be nice.

Comment: something like localhost/listing/property-id-23

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will give you a secured URI :

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF8');
function toAscii($str, $replace=array(), $delimiter='-') {
 if( !empty($replace) ) {
  $str = str_replace((array)$replace, ' ', $str);
 }

 $clean = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $str);
 $clean = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/_|+ -]/", '', $clean);
 $clean = strtolower(trim($clean, '-'));
 $clean = preg_replace("/[\/_|+ -]+/", $delimiter, $clean);

 return $clean;
}
```

Exemple :

```
echo toAscii("Custom`delimiter*example", array('*', '`'));
returns: custom-delimiter-example
```

Just take the name of the product and convert it to URI. **Don't forget to check if URI already exists ;)**